# How to have a session variable during a foursquare redirect

Tags: php, foursquare

I am trying to keep the username variable alive while I redirect to foursquare for oauth purposes.  I am using Amazon EC2 servers.
Here is the relevant code:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_GET['username']))
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_GET['username']
    header("Location: https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate?clientid=(clientidHere)&responsetype=code&redirect_uri=http://redirecturi");
}
if (isset($_GET['code']))
{ 
    echo $_SESSION['username'];
}
```

Comment: Is your redirect_uri literally [http://redirecturi](http://redirecturi) or on your actual app are you using your registered redirect URI (registered https://foursquare.com/developers/apps) for this application? Looking at your code, your redirect URI should probably be the same page as this.

Comment: the http://redirecturi is just a place holder for the url I am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I just had to use cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Think the issue here is in your parameters. They should be:

- `client_id`
- `response_type`
- `redirect_uri`

See: https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth